# Dreamweaver CS6 Error?

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a page in DW that has a black background. In Design View of the page the page shows as white instead of black. I am not sure why this is. I can add inline styles to the entire page as follows to get the page black:

```
<body>
<div style="background-color:#000" class="wrap_fullwidth">
<div style="background-color:#000" class="center">
<div style="background-color:#000" class="img-center">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" />
    </div>
    <p style="background-color:#000"> </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS for the page and the way it normally is:

```
html, body{
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:"Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   line-height:23px;
   color:#f3f3f3;
   background:#000;
}

.wrap_fullwidth {width:100%; position:relative; float:left; 
                 clear:both; padding-top:20px; }

.center{width:940px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; 
       clear:both; padding:0px 10px; display:block;}

 p{ margin-bottom:20px; text-align:justify;}

.img-center{ text-align: center; }
```

The design view should show the page as it appears with css etc. I do not understand why the white is showing when the css clearly shows black as a background. The good thing is the page in the browser shows correctly but this makes things a pain if I work in Design View. (Which I do use)

Ideas or thoughts as to how to fix this?

Note: CS5 and CS5.5 did not have this behavior. Only CS6.

Comment: Not seeing the problem with the code supplied (I even removed the background color inline styles. Tried in CS6 on Mac Lion if it matters at all. FWIW: you may want to try using background-color in the html,body style definition rather than just background. Also, please post the full code that you're using, there may be other issues causig what you're seeing.

Comment: @DaniloCelic - Thanks for your response, I got it figured out. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my Reset for the CSS was causing DW to show a transparent background (thus white) instead of black.

The reset contained this property: `background:transparent;`

Once I removed that from the reset all worked fine.

*Update*: I had wondered if the way DW CS6 was reading the CSS if there was a bug or not, after filing a bug report I received this reply:

> I was able to reproduce as per your steps and have logged a backlog item for the same. It will be fixed in future release.